# Puppeteer function to submit a form repeatedly a certain number of times, looping through some data

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have a HTML page with a text-area and a submit button; Using Puppeteer, I want to type into the text-area, submit and repeat the process over and over again a number of times.

My attempt is typing the first message and then starts typing the 2nd before submitting, or it starts typing in the middle of the sentence.

Here below is a snippet of my attempted Nodejs code.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
 
  await page.setDefaultTimeout(0);
  await page.goto('https://agents.moderationinterface.com/login');
  await page.waitForSelector("input[name='username']");
  await page.type("input[name='username']", "EN-7158", {delay: 10});
  await page.type("input[name='password']", "meYufr5Cru3rO4a", {delay: 10});
  await page.click("#login-submit");
  await page.waitForNavigation();

  const arrayofTexts = ["aaa","bbb","ccc"];
  await page.waitForSelector("#chat-windows-message-textarea:not([disabled])");
  await page.type("#chat-windows-message-textarea", arrayofTexts[0]);
  await page.waitForTimeout(5000);
  await page.waitForSelector("input[name='submit']");
  await page.click("input[name='submit']");

  await page.waitForSelector("#chat-windows-message-textarea:not([disabled])");
  await page.type("#chat-windows-message-textarea", arrayofTexts[1],{delay: 10});
  await page.click("button[type='submit']");
  await page.waitForNavigation();

  await page.waitForSelector("#chat-windows-message-textarea:not([disabled])");
  await page.type("#chat-windows-message-textarea", arrayofTexts[2],{delay: 10});
  await page.click("button[type='submit']");
  await browser.close();
})();
```

My code is automatically typing the first message and then starts typing the 2nd before submitting, or it starts typing in the middle of the sentence.

Comment: Welcome to SO! 

I don't know puppeteer, but in your code you First do `click` before `waitForNavigation`. Second you do `click` without `waitForNavigation`. Third you do `click ` before `waitForNavigation` again. Fourth `click ` without `waitForNavigation`. This seems a little inconsistent to me. Looking at the docs it looks like waitForNavigation happens _before_ the click: https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.waitfornavigation/

Comment: Any navigation triggered by a click needs to be awaited along with the click: `await Promise.all([page.waitForNavigation(), page.click()]);` is the general pattern.